# How can a menu item (non-custom) in a spreadsheet be invoked using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Google Apps Script.

I am looking for options to invoke a menu operation through the google script in a spreadsheet. I am using a connector add-on that connects to a datasource, runs a report and return the result set to a sheet. The plugin does not provide support for auto refresh of the data, so I have to manually click another link to refresh the data every time.

The requirement is to define a trigger with a function to invoke this refresh menu at regular intervals.

Seeking some guidance on how to get the handle to the menu item for the plugin and invoke it through a function in the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, could you maybe share a copy of your sheet? What is the menu that you want to run apps Script? There seems to be no way to "refresh" the UI menu.

Comment: Hi Raserhin, Sorry for the late response, I have attached the screenshot of the menu item in the below answer for reference.

Comment: @BalajiRaman Please do NOT use an answer to provide more information about your question. In any event, there is no screenshot.